# casting to Integer is not working properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

execute these and check the result why is it so ?

```
declare @a decimal(8,3) =235.363
declare @b int          =1

select case @b
            when 1 then cast(@a as int)
            when 2 then CAST(@a as decimal(8,3))
end

Result  : 235.000
```

---

```
declare @a decimal(8,3) =235.363
declare @b int          =1

select case @b
            when 1 then cast(@a as int)
            --when 2 then CAST(@a as decimal(8,3))
end

Result  : 235
```

---

```
declare @a decimal(8,3) =235.363
declare @b int          =1

select case @b
            when 1 then cast(@a as tinyint)
            when 2 then CAST(@a as float)
end

Result : 235
```

Comment: Well, question is: what were you expecting??

Answer (score 2):

What you see is not what you get.

For the column *type*, SQL Server picks the correct, more wide type (`float` over `tinyint`, `decimal` over `int`). You can verify that by doing [`select into`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) instead of just select.

It's just the display rules that are different.
When the selected column type is `float`, you don't see the trailing `.000` when there is no fractional part.
For `decimal` with explicit positions set, such as `decimal(8,3)`, you will see the trailing `.000` even if there's no fractional part. If you remove the specifier and only leave `decimal` as the column type, the `.000` will disappear.

All that does not affect the actual column type, which is always the widest one.

Comment: see the last section it is returning tinyint not float

Comment: @Nighil It is returning `float` which by default is displayed without the fractional part. Try [`select into`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) instead of `select`, you will see it.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is documented in [the BOL entry for `CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> **Return Types**
>
> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   `result_expressions` and the optional `else_result_expression`. For more
>   information, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

If you follow the link to data type precedence you will see that `float` has higher precedence than `decimal` which in turn has higher precedence than `tinyint` so this behaviour is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Probably cast operation will cast all the options to a bigger type.

From MSDN:

> The data types of input_expression and each when_expression must be
>   the same or must be an implicit conversion.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: how it checks the bigger type?

Comment: select case @b
            when 1 then cast(@a as tinyint)
            when 2 then CAST(@a as float)
end
ok then what about this?

Comment: float precedence is 10 tiny int is 18 then tinyint comes as output

Answer (score 0):

**Casting to Integer is not working properly.**

## Your statement is not correct!

In `CASE` statement, you can only return one type of data, so according to your statement you can return either `INT` or `decimal(8,3)`, since your case statement has `decimal(8,3)` so here `INT` data is implicitly converted to decimal! **Please see below example:**, always try to use same return type in `CASE` statement to get proper and expected result, thanks.

1.

```
select case @b
    when 1 then CAST(@a as int) -- return type INT
when 2 then CAST(@a as int) -- return type INT
end
```

2.

```
select case @b
     when 1 then CAST(@a as int) -- return type INT and then converted to decimal(8,3)
 when 2 then CAST(@a as decimal(8,3)) -- return type return type INT 
end
```

Comment: that i know but my question is why it return decimal in first one and tiny int in last one